# Google Map distance-matrix api Serverside multiple address by latlong

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, distance-matrix

In
https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-distance-matrix
example we can add multiple destincation as latlong pair,

The server side code is like

```
string Test = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Lat1,long1&destinations=Lat2,long2&sensor=false"
```

Now the question is how to use it in multiple origin destination mode
Can we 
something like

```
string Test = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Lat1,long1,lat2,long2&destinations=Lat3,long3,Lat4,long4&sensor=false"
```

**Example**

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=23.020284,72.4396566&destinations=22.3039702,70.7671403&sensor=false
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=23.027100,72.508000&destinations=22.999500,72.600300&sensor=false

Combo of this two

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=23.020284,72.4396566,23.027100,72.508000&destinations=22.3039702,70.7671403,22.999500,72.600300&sensor=false

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I solved it by using "|" delimiter.
Thank you every one

Comment: A full example would be helpful in order to disambiguate WHERE the "|" would go.

Answer (score 0):

OPs own answer works, just adding one with a clear example. Notice the pipe (`|`) separation between lat, long pairs. an array of arrays `[[a,b], [c,d]]` would not work.

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=23.020284,72.4396566|23.027100,72.508000&destinations=22.3039702,70.7671403|22.999500,72.600300&sensor=false$key=AIza....OgXQ
```

Answer (score 0):

Another cool way to get directions for multiple coordinates is to encode all origins and destinations into polylines ([Google's Encoded Polyline Algorithm](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm)).

### Google Docs: Encoded Polyline

> Alternatively, you can supply an encoded set of coordinates using the [Encoded Polyline Algorithm](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm). This is particularly useful if you have a large number of origin points, because the URL is significantly shorter when using an encoded polyline. - Encoded polylines must be prefixed with `enc:` and followed by a colon `:`. For example: `origins=enc:gfo}EtohhU:` - You can also include multiple encoded polylines, separated by the pipe character `|`. For example: `origins=enc:wc~oAwquwMdlTxiKtqLyiK:|enc:c~vnAamswMvlTor@tjGi}L:|enc:udymA{~bxM:`

There are client libraries already built for most common languages. For example `klaxit/fast-polylines` ([github link](https://github.com/klaxit/fast-polylines))  gem for ruby.

### Usage

```
require "fast_polylines"

origins = FastPolylines.encode([[38.5, -120.2], [40.7, -120.95], [43.252, -126.453]])
destinations = FastPolylines.encode([[38.6, -120.4], [40.4, -120.2], [43.26, -126.463]])


url = http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=enc:#{origins}:&destinations=enc:#{destinations}:&sensor=false$key=AIza....OgXQ
```

*** Note that encoded origins and destinations need the `enc:` prefix and `:` suffix. Ex: `origins=enc:XXXX:`

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution ..
use the link in this format :https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco&key=YOUR_API_KEY.
this is working fine

Comment: This does not addresses OP question. It does not specifies how to get directions for multiple places at once.

Comment: You can add multiple destination or origin by "|" (Pipe) Separated.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?destinations=m13bb|LS9 7TU&language=GB&mode=bicycling&origins=Skipton Castle, The Bailey, Skipton BD23 1AW, United Kingdom&key=Your API KEY